# Warning when presenting UIActivityViewController inside a SwiftUI sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I use UIActivityViewController to allow my SwiftUI app to share content with other activities:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ShareSheet : UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    var items: [Any]
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
          
        return ac
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

To make it clear, I will use the following simple code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showForImageShare: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .onTapGesture {
                    showForImageShare.toggle()
                }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showForImageShare){
            let image = "Hello everybody"
            
            ShareSheet(items: [image])
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following warning in the console:

```
2022-10-23 23:41:07.692216+0300 Test UIActivityViewController[92164:30374157] [LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionReusableView that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIActivityContentFooterView: 0x15cd56340; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (16 244.333; 361 52); layer = <CALayer: 0x600001ab8180>>
```

I use Xcode 14, Deployment Target: 16.0

Could you please help me to find the best way to present UIActivityViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isActivityViewPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Share Link") {
            self.isActivityViewPresented = true
        }
        .background(
            ActivityView(
                isPresented: $isActivityViewPresented,
                activityItmes: [URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74174661/warning-when-presenting-uiactivityviewcontroller-inside-a-swiftui-sheet")!]
            )
        )
    }
}

public struct ActivityView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    public let activityItmes: [Any]
    public let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    
    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        UIViewController()
    }
    
    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController (
            activityItems: activityItmes,
            applicationActivities: applicationActivities
        )
        
        if isPresented && uiViewController.presentedViewController == nil {
            uiViewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
        }
        activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (_, _, _, _) in
            isPresented = false
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @dortus47 but I still see the same warning messages (besides other messages). Actually, I'm new to iOS development and I'm basically working on SwiftUI, I use UIKit only when I need it. This warning message doesn't affect on the app working on the simulator or on my device, but I'm afraid problems will arise on some other devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
 struct ActivityView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let activityItems: [Any]
    let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        UIViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        if isPresented && uiViewController.presentedViewController == nil {
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
                activityItems: activityItems,
                applicationActivities: applicationActivities
            )
            activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (_, _, _, _) in
                isPresented = false
            }
            uiViewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).